# Functions set in a loop return always the last loop value

Tags: function, loops, object

I'm trying to create a function object, trying to attach to each key a function that return a value that depends also on this key value.

Here is a little example:

```
let obj = {}
for (letter of ['l', 'h', 'v']) {
    obj[letter] = function (name) {
        return getFullString (name + ' has letter ' + letter);
    }
}

function getFullString (string) {
    return 'Mr. ' + string;
}
```

The problem is that I always get a value that is linked only to the last key ('v'):

```
console.log (obj.l('John')); //Mr. John has letter v
console.log (obj.h('John')); //Mr. John has letter v
console.log (obj.v('John')); //Mr. John has letter v
```

What's wrong with it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved creating inside the loop, a temporary variable that stores the value of for-of iterator, by valueOf() function:

```
let obj = {};
for (char of ['l', 'h', 'v']) {
    let letter = char.valueOf();
    obj[letter] = function (name) {            
        return getFullString (name + ' has letter ' + letter);
    }
}

console.log (obj.l('John')); //Mr. John has letter l
console.log (obj.h('John')); //Mr. John has letter h
console.log (obj.v('John')); //Mr. John has letter v
```